# Oracle apex 19.2 show user if collapsible report is empty

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I need to show the user if any collapsible report has rows in it or empty (when it is in collapsed state)

I'm trying to find a global and simple solution that can work on all tables.

currently, my only idea is to make dynamic action ("notify empty") for each report after refresh. then check in 'Client-side Condition' with javascript if it has rows with:

`$(this.triggeringElement).find('.nodatafound').length==1;`

then I'm coloring the collapsible icon to red/green accordingly with:

`$(this.triggeringElement).find('.t-Button--icon').css("background-color", "red")`

[image]

This solution works (for classic and interactive reports, but I don't have interactive grid anyway)
But I have many tables, and even if I put my javascript code in functions, it repeats itself a lot. I'm looking for a more maintainable option. Something like built in dynamic action for all reports that I can put in a single place.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [also use](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/09/orcle-apex-hide-region-if-no-data-found.html) the after-refresh client side condition to test for any results.

I've been thinking about a global method for this for some time, so I thought I'd finally give something a go.

You could have an after-refresh dynamic action on the global page that tests any classic report using the jQuery selector `.t-Region`

Then have the same client condition and actions on the triggering element.

The selector on the global page can be extended to include IR as well. If you want to nominate which regions to test, then you could add a class the region's Appearance - CSS Classes attribute.

Alternatively, you could use the `:not()` CSS selector on the dynamic action as a way to *exclude* nominated regions using the same attribute.

Comment: Yes I think your link is what inspired me in the first place. I will try your idea on the global page

Comment: Thanks, the global JQuery selector works (I picked the ".t-Region--hideShow" class). But the problem in this selector that it refers to all regions which are collapsible, even non-table ones, is there any way to make it specific only to tables region?

Comment: There's a few options here, as eluded to in my original response. You could target nominated regions by adding your own class, ignore nominated regions, or perhaps you could modify the selector and subsequent actions to look for '.t-Report .nodatafound', then head to $(this.triggeringElement).closest('.t-Region') to action your needs. Probably not a big issue if only hiding when 0 records, but in your case I presume you also have a false action that's tripping you up.

Comment: To sum it up, I added my own class to the reports, to be used by JQuery selector in P0 and then on the client-side condition: $(this.triggeringElement).find('.[ELEMENT_TO_FIND]').length==1 ----------- when ELEMENT_TO_FIND can be one of this, according to the report type  1).a-IRR-noDataMsg 2).nodatafound 3).a-GV-noDataMsg:visible. --------------- This working also for the false action and specific for each table

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered querying the tables for row counts separately/first and save each count to a page item that's used to calculate each region display?

Long ago I had a similar need and I solved it that way. It's a bit more Oracle code, but Oracle's good at that, right?

See screenshot below: [image]

Comment: Yes, Oracle code is easier to maintain, but as I understand this solution is not global and needs to handle each table separately right?

Comment: I guess I never understood the original question. Sorry for the noise!